# Прямое чтение с диска

Tags: ассемблер

Как прочитать сектор с диска ( в частном случае,с карты памяти) ?
  ( интересуют,прежде всего,записи FAT ).

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно воспользоваться прерыванием `13h`.